# How to split ytt method definition from schema

Tags: ytt

I'm trying to split a method definition from the schema. This is a case loosely inspired by the official [how-to](https://carvel.dev/ytt/#example:example-splitting-a-template). If the following code is present in the same file, it works well. However if I'm splitting the method definition into a separate file the following way, it results in an error.

`svc.yaml`:

```
#@ load("@ytt:data", "data")
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels: #@ labels(with_version=True)
  name: #@ data.values.promOperatorName
  namespace: #@ data.values.namespace
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    targetPort: http
  selector: #@ labels()
```

`labels.yaml`:

```
#@ load("@ytt:data", "data")

#@ def labels(with_version=False):
  app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  app.kubernetes.io/name: prometheus-operator
  #@ if with_version:
  app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.53.1
  #@ end
#@ end
```

Applied via: `ytt -f labels.yaml -f svc.yaml -f data.yaml` this yields

```
ytt: Error: 
- undefined: labels
    svc.yaml:7 |   labels: #@ labels(with_version=True)
- undefined: labels
    svc.yaml:16 |   selector: #@ labels()
```

Apparently the `def labels()` method definition is not picked-up during processing.

ytt version `0.38.0`

Answer (score 1):

The file carrying the method definition should be loaded as a library. Therefore it should be renamed to `labels.lib.yaml` (`.lib.yaml` suffix is mandatory for libraries).

Afterwards the library and the respective methods should be loaded in the appropriate template file, in our case in `svc.yaml` via:

```
#@ load("labels.lib.yaml", "labels")
```

Comment: Nice! Details about how this `load()` function works can be found here: https://carvel.dev/ytt/docs/v0.40.0/lang-ref-load/#docs